# Retrieve contents of all stack traces being printed to the console?

Tags: java, logging, exception

I want to individually log every unique error I have, as searching though a dozen log files each **+10k** lines in length is time wasting and tedious.

I catch all exceptions I possibly can, but oftentimes other threads or libraries will shoot off their own errors without any way to process them myself.

Is there any workaround for this?

(E.G. an event for when `printStackTrace()` is called.)

Comment: If you're using log4j you could specify different log levels for the packages you're not interested in. Would that work?

Comment: No, I need to be able to get the contents of all exceptions thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any workaround for this?
>   (E.G. an event for when printStackTrace() is called.)

[Remap System.err](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setErr-java.io.PrintStream-) to intercept throwables.  If you look at the source code for `Throwable.printStackTrace()` you'll see that it indirectly calls `System.err.println(this);`

For example:

```
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class SpyPrintStream extends PrintStream {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setErr(new SpyPrintStream(System.err));
        System.setOut(new SpyPrintStream(System.out));
        new Exception().printStackTrace();
    }

    public SpyPrintStream(PrintStream src) {
        super(src);
    }

    @Override
    public void println(Object x) {
        if (x instanceof Throwable) {
           super.println("Our spies detected "+ x.getClass().getName());
        }
        super.println(x);
    }
}
```

Keep in mind there is all kinds of issues with using this code and it is not going to work in cases where `printStackTrace` is called with stream that is not standard stream.

You could always do a deep dive into [java.lang.instrument](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html) if you really want to trap all exceptions.

> I catch all exceptions I possibly can, but oftentimes other threads or libraries will shoot off their own errors without any way to process them myself.

Most libraries either throw exceptions back to the caller or use a logging framework.  Capture the exception or configure the logging framework.

> I want to individually log every unique error I have, as searching though a dozen log files each +10k lines in length is time wasting and tedious.

Logging frameworks include options to deal with this.  [DuplicateMessageFilter](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html#DuplicateMessageFilter) is an example.

Answer (score 0):

Food for thought:

```
public class DemoClass {

    private Map<String, Exception> myExceptions = new HashMap<>();

    public void demoMethod() {
        try {
            // throwing an exception for illustration
            throw new IOException("some message");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            myExceptions.putIfAbsent(e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);

            // actually handle the exception
            ...
        }
    }

    public void finished() {
        for (Exception e : myExceptions.values()) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

You could store any exception you haven't seen yet. If your specific scenario allows for a better way to ensure you only save an exception only once you should prefer that over mapping by `Exception.getLocalizedMessage()`